# Upgrading 4.0.10 to Plone 5 (missing IRegistry?)

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to upgrade a Plone 4.0.10 site to 5.0.  I went through the upgrade to 4.3.6 and somewhat painfully got it to work there.  In my `Data.fs` I have two Plone sites:  the site in question, and another one that has nothing but the default content (News, Events, Users).  When I moved the `Data.fs` and blobs from the 4.3.6 to the Plone 5 instance, the "empty" site upgraded fine.  However, if I even try to go to the ZMI root for the production site, or to load the site, I get this:

```
    2015-12-05 17:19:24 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1449364764.10.146181213601 http://localhost:8080/mysite
    Traceback (innermost last):
      Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
      Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 444, in traverse
      Module ZPublisher.BeforeTraverse, line 97, in __call__
      Module Products.CMFCore.PortalObject, line 75, in __before_publishing_traverse__
      Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
      Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
      Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
      Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
      Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
      Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
      Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
      Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
      Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
      Module plone.app.theming.plugins.hooks, line 33, in onRequest
      Module plone.app.theming.policy, line 91, in isThemeEnabled
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enabled'
```

I don't know why `plone.app.theming` is involved, since the old site had no Diazo theme, and I'm just loading the ZMI. Also, the problem seems to be that there is no `IRegistry`:

In `plone.app.theming.policy.getSettings`:

```
    def getSettings(self):
    """Settings for current theme."""
    registry = queryUtility(IRegistry)
```

And `registry` at this point is `None`, and so is `settings` in `plone.app.theming.policy.isThemeEnabled`.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: This looks like a Bug, you may fill a bug report --> https://plone.org/community

Comment: plone.app.theming has to be installed in Plone 4. Include p.a.t in your Plone 4.3.6 Site and re-upgrade.

Comment: @pabo, you are right.  If you want to put this in the answers, I'll accept it.

Comment: So basically, when starting from a pre-Diazo version of Plone, one should never attempt to upgrade to 5 without going through an intermediate step at one of the later 4.2 or 4.3 versions.  That intermediate step is necessary to install plone.app.theming before moving on to 5.

Comment: I created an issue in github:  https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1284

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plone.app.theming has to be installed in Plone 4. Include p.a.t in your Plone 4.3.6 Site and re-upgrade.
([How to upgrade sites to Plone 5, 24:15](https://youtu.be/bQ-IpO-7F00?t=24m15s))